# Is there any ratio for Responsive Full Background Image

Tags: css, background-image, responsive, aspect-ratio

Is there any aspect ratio that needs to be considered for full background responsive image? Image size is 1361 x 1216. [Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLd20.jpg)

Below is the CSS used,

```
body{
background-image:url('../images/bg-img.jpg');
background-position:center center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-size: contain;
  }
```

But the result is [background-size: contain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COEku.jpg)

If background-size: cover is used the top and bottom portion of the image are cropped.

Comment: Please check this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Did not get the solution, I have put the image on how the result is shown, any other detail needs to be added?

Comment: please provide your html code too.. for example with codepen.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick ;)

```
body {
    background-image:url('../images/bg-img.jpg');
    background-position:center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

> background-size: WIDTH HEIGHT;

---

EDIT: you could do something like this:

```
body{
background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLd20.jpg');
background-position:center center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
}
@media(min-width: 768px){
  body {
    background-size: 100% auto;
  }
}
@media(max-width: 767px){
  body {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
}
```

> Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BpJWOR

Note that "100% 100%" will stretch the background disproportionately. you can use "auto 100%" instead at the "max-width 767px section"

You could also experiment with 110% or higher. just keep trying until it gets the perfect look... welcome to responsive webdesign :P

Comment: It still crops the top and bottom part of the image

Comment: please provide your html code. then i will take a look again.. for example with codepen.io

Comment: if you dont want to crop the bottom and top of the image you shoud set the height to 100% and the width to auto like "background-size: auto 100%;" if this doesnt help, i need to take a look at your code.

Comment: background-size: auto 100% also does not work... I have given link to codepen

Comment: This gives the desired output. Thanks a lot